# Django: how can I save objects to the database using FormView and ajax?

Tags: python, ajax, django, python-3.x, django-forms

I am building an application using `google maps api` where users can add and save markers on the map. I am using ajax to send the form containing marker attributes to the backend. I am using `django's` heleper `FormView`:

**ajax.js:**

```
$(document).on('submit', '.add_marker_form', function(event){

  event.preventDefault();

  // parse form attributes:
    // (irrelevent code here)

  $.ajax({
      method: 'POST',       // or 'type'
      url: '/map/saveMarker/',
      data: data,          // the four attributes
      csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()

      success: function(data){
      console.log("marker saved");
  },
      error: function(data){
      console.log("marker not saved");
   }
  });

 }) // document
```

**forms.py**

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import myModel


class SaveMarkerForm(ModelForm):
      class Meta:
          model = myModel
          fields = ['title', 'url', 'latitude', 'longitude']
```

**mixin.py**

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

  class AjaxFormMixin(object):

      def form_invalid(self, form):
          response = super(AjaxFormMixin, self).form_invalid(form)
          if self.request.is_ajax():
             return JsonResponse(form.errors, status=400)
          else:
            return response

      def form_valid(self, form):
          form.save()
          response = super(AjaxFormMixin, self).form_valid(form)
          if self.request.is_ajax():
             data = {
              'message': "Successfully submitted data."
             }
            return JsonResponse(data)
          else:
            return response
```

**views.py**

```
import requests
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView
from .forms import SaveMarkerForm
from .mixin import AjaxFormMixin


class SaveMarkerView(AjaxFormMixin, FormView):
      form_class = SaveMarkerForm
      template_name = 'map.html'
      success_url = '/'
```

But after submitting the form, the objects are not saved in the database. 
As you can see I added `form.save()` to `form_valid` method as suggested here:

> [Django FormView Not Saving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20852744/django-formview-not-saving)

I also tried using `UpdateView` instead as suggested here:

> [Django. Simple FormView not saving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31978740/django-simple-formview-not-saving)

and also tried other solutions  but none of them worked. 
so please help me. where is the problem in my code? what am I missing.

Comment: What response do you get? Note that your Ajax success callback doesn't actually check what's in the response, which could just as easily be the form errors from form_invalid.

Comment: @DanielRoseman thanks for the answer. I added console.log('data') to success and now it prints my whole html file in the console?? I am really lost

Answer (score 0):

Are you [passing a CSRF token with the AJAX request](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/csrf/#ajax)? If not that could be why your form is invalid.

This post explains how to [include CSRF token in AJAX post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44481635/8741781).

Comment: thanks for your answer. Yes I am sending it like this: `csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()`. I removed it from the code above because I wanted to shorten it.